# How could I randomise the order of a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have to make a quiz for school and I am storing all of my questions in a MySQL table (using a database is a requirement of the project.) Is there any way I can randomise the order of the records of a table so that I can then easily pull them into the java program when necessary, just starting from the top and working my way down, without having to always pick a random one and therefore risking duplicates?

Comment: It's simpler to just shuffle the array when you get the result. What is in the backend?

Comment: Yeah I thought that but I have more questions in the table than positions in the array. I have already sorted out how to randomise in what order the questions appear, but when I am entering them into the array it always just takes the first few questions of the top of the table.

Comment: Tried ORDER BY RAND() ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see multiple ways to handle your problem, but would need more information of your usecase to guess how viable they are.

The first one coming to mind would be to write the already picked question into another table, together with the clients id. So when you pick the next question you can simply exclude those which are already in the other table.

To "reorder" your table the easiest way would be to simply add an sorting column.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `questionId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `sort` varchar(36) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`questionId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `sort` column will contain UUIDs, so there most probably won't be collisions.

Now, to change the order I simply update those UUIDs with new ones:

```
UPDATE questions SET sort = uuid() ORDER BY rand();
```

To select some questions, just use that column to order the result.

```
SELECT questionId, question FROM questions ORDER BY sort;
```

An `index` on the `sort` column might be useful when you have a lot of questions, say thousands. I guess it will be fast enough without one.

Instead of `UUID`s you can also use some less spaceconsuming data, it just has to be something relatively random.